# Your Kedro project version 0.17.6 does not match Kedro package version

Tags: python, kedro

when running `kedro ipython` into a cloned repo, I get:

```
_version_mismatch_error(metadata_dict["kedro_init_version"]))
ValueError: Your Kedro project version 0.17.6 does not match Kedro package version
0.18.14 you are running. Make sure to update your project template. See https://github.com/kedro-org/kedro/blob/main/RELEASE.md for how to migrate your Kedro project.
```

The thing is I don't have admin priviledges to downgrade python to 3.8 zhich would be required to install the matching project version 0.17.6. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Kedro project was created with Kedro 0.17.6, but you have Kedro 0.18.14 (latest stable version) installed. You have two options:

- You can downgrade to Kedro 0.17.* (I believe any 0.17.* version should work, please double check). You have mentioned that you can't change your Python version but not what version are you running at the moment. Both 0.17 and 0.18 support Python 3.8 and Python 3.7.
- You can update your project template. There is no standard process for this, it's kind of manual at the moment. You can have a look at the changelog (link on the error message) and manually adjust the template.